# Which axiom can almost determine the magma with one element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma

The axiom $((a * b) * c) * (a * ((a * c) * a)) = c$ uniquely determines Boolean algebra, an example of a single axiom giving a magma an "interesting" structure. What is the fewest number of times that * can occur in an axiom for a magma while still only allowing the empty magma and the magma with one element and a magma with $2$ elements?

Comment: You can do zero: $\forall x,y,z(x=y\vee y=z\vee x=z)$. If you're looking for an equational axiom, none exists since any equation with a model of size $>1$ has arbitrarily large models.

Comment: I was looking for an equational axiom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the comments, the OP is looking for an equational axiom. No such equation exists, however, due to the following fact:

> If $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ are each models of an equation $\mathsf{E}$, then the direct product $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}$ is also a model of $\mathsf{E}$.

In particular, if $\mathsf{E}$ has a model of size $2$, then it has models of size $2^k$ for every $k$. So no equation can allow a model with two elements but not allow models with more elements.

Comment: That fact is a special case of Birkhoff’s theorem, right?

Comment: @GregNisbet Yes, it's part of the easy part of Birkhoff's theorem. The hard part is of course the other direction: that $\mathsf{HSP}(\mathbb{K})$ is a variety after all.